# How can footballers head or hit the ball so high?

Tags: football

In football(soccer), we often see defenders heading the ball almost 25-30 yards, and seemingly light touches taking the ball very high. It's also said that the football is very light and hence is difficult to keep low while shooting. Why is that? Is the ball filled differently? Or are those balls made in a different way?

Comment: Welcome. This is a reasonable question, but perhaps it has to do more with technique (as Philip has stated) than it does with the ball itself?

Comment: Yes it's probably that, but it just seemed strange that the ball could travel so far after being headed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fundamental difference in the ball or anything else - professional players just have (much) better technique than you or me, so everything just happens much faster, and speed speeds height.

Comment: Okay, it just seemed improbable that they could head it so far, with the same kind of ball that we play with

Comment: May I also know why someone could have down voted this question? It's a reasonable question I have